# Submit multiple forms by their ID using AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

I am looking to submit multiple forms by their ID using AJAX, the ID's are found and produced using the jQuery below. Each form will of course have individual unique ID's, currently being created by the variable i.

```
     <script>
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {

    var wrap = $(this).closest('div.form_wrap');

    wrap.find('form').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).prop('id');
        var i = $('#'+id);
        console.log(i);
    });

});
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<?php $f = 0;?>  
@foreach ($workouts as $workout)
<?php $formid="form_".$x."_".$f;?>
{!! Form::open(array('route' => 'workoutshared.store', 'method' => 'POST', 'ID' => $formid)) !!}
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    {{ Form::hidden('user_id', Auth::user()->id)}}
    {{ Form::hidden('date', $entry)}}
    {{ Form::hidden('weight', $workout->weight)}}
    {{ Form::hidden('exercise', $workout->exercise)}}
    {{ Form::hidden('reps', $workout->reps)}}
    {{ Form::hidden('sets', $workout->sets)}}              
    {{ Form::checkbox('share', 1, array('class' => 'form-control'))}}
{!! Form::close() !!}     
    <tr>
        <th>{{$workout->exercise}}</th>
        <td>{{$workout->weight}}</td>
        <td>{{$workout->reps}}</td>
        <td>{{$workout->sets}}</td>
    </tr>

<?php $f++; endforeach;?>
```

**UPDATE**

```
<script>
$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {

    var wrap = $(this).closest('div.form_wrap');

    wrap.find('form').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).prop('id');
        var i = $('#'+id);
        console.log(i);
        $(i).submit(function() {
        var that = $(this),
            url = that.attr('action'),
            type = that.attr('method'),
            data = {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();

            data[name] = value;
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Comment: Where is your HTML ?

Comment: what is the specific problem and question?

Comment: note that `<form>` can't be a sibling of `<tr>` ... it's invalid html

Comment: I have very little experience with AJAX and wish to submit forms with the ID generated by the jQuery variable of i. There will be a variable amounts of the forms.

Comment: @JamesParsons You might be generated this question yesterday also,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39804482/looping-through-a-variable-amount-of-ids-and-submitting-forms-by-the-ids-gener/39804515#39804515

Comment: @Loading.. your answer yesterday only submitted the first Id. I am now looking to use AJAX to submit all

Answer (score 0):

You can submit the all the forms using:

```
wrap.find('form').each(function() {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
var i = $('#'+id);
  $(i).submit(function() {
        var that = $(this),
            url = that.attr('action'),
            type = that.attr('method'),
            data = {};

        that.find('[name]').each(function(index, value) {
            var that = $(this),
                name = that.attr('name'),
                value = that.val();

            data[name] = value;
        });

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: type,
            data: data,
            success: function(response) {
                console.log(response);
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Obviously using this takes the data already used in the form and submits it to the current action with the current method.

So basically this works if you're using GET and POST and different submit locations (actions).

Edit: I also changed .prop() to .attr() according to the jquery docs: http://api.jquery.com/attr/ .prop() isn't a correct usage in this scenario

Comment: Thanks for the reply but it is failing. Could you take a look and see why it could be?

Comment: Why is it failing? What is happening? Are there any console errors?

Comment: Nothing at all in the console. I think jQuery could be failing at the start. There isnt any document or on click #button as per `$(document).on('click', '#button', function() {

    var wrap = $(this).closest('div.form_wrap');

    wrap.find('form').each(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        var i = $('#'+id);
        console.log(i);
    });` I have tried adapting your code but with no luck.

Comment: I'll change the `$(i).on('submit', function() {` to `$(i).submit(function() {` if you're using it inside an onClick

Comment: Still failing it is pulling through the variable i correctly now though. Could it be a problem with the URL or type. I have posted an update.